# Login function works on subdomain but not on main domain

Tags: authentication, csrf, login-script

How could it be that i have a script and a login function work on subdomain but not the other? Using same MySQL DB username and password. Identical code wont work.

```
    if(isset($_POST['Login'])) {

        try
        {
            // Run CSRF check, on POST data, in exception mode, for 10 minutes, in one-time mode.
            NoCSRF::check( 'csrf_token', $_POST, true, 60*10, false );
            $gump = new GUMP();
            $_POST = $gump->sanitize($_POST); // You don't have to sanitize, but it's safest to do      so.

            $is_valid = GUMP::is_valid($_POST, array(
                                    'entry' => 'required',
                                    'password' => 'required'

            ));
            if($is_valid === true) {
                login($db , $_POST['entry'] ,$_POST['password'] );

            }else{
                    $_SESSION['Error'] = $is_valid; // set error messages
                    header("location:".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); // redirect to php self
                    exit;
            }


        }
        catch ( Exception $e )
        {
            // CSRF attack detected
                    $result[] = 'Session expired form ignored try again .'; //$e->getMessage() . ' Form ignored.';
                    $_SESSION['Error'] = $result; // set error messages
                    header("location:".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); // redirect to php self
                    exit;
        }

}


function login($db , $entry , $password) {
        //session_destroy();
        $entry    = (string)$entry;
        $password = (string)$password;
        /* $db->select($table , $columns , $where ) */
        $datas    = $db->select("user", [
        "user_id",
        "username",
        "email"
        ],  [

         "AND"=>[

                "OR" => [
                    "username" => "$entry",
                    "email" => "$entry"
                    ],
                    "password"=>md5("$password"),
                    "status"  => '1',
                    "verify_status"  => '1',
                ]           

        ]);
        $error = $db->error(); // error
                    if(empty($error[2])) { // if error empty

                            if(is_array($datas) && count($datas) > 0) { // if select return result

                            extract($datas[0]);
                            $_SESSION['user_id']        = $user_id;
                            $_SESSION['user_name']      = $username;
                            $_SESSION['user_email']     = $email;
                            $_SESSION['user_is_logged'] = TRUE;
                            $_SESSION['Success'][] = "Successfully Logged In :)"; // set error messages
                            header("location:".BASE_URL); // redirect to php self
                            exit;
                            }else { // else invalid attempt
                            $_SESSION['Error'][] = "Invalid Credentials or you may not verified."; // set error messages
                            header("location:".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); // redirect to php self
                            exit;
                            }
                    }else {

                            $_SESSION['Error'][] = "Error on query.."; // set error messages
                            header("location:".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); // redirect to php self
                            exit;
                    }
}
```

So when i bring the code over the the catch block activates as if CSRF attack detected. What the heck is going on?`
NoCSRF & Gump are identical. Constants are the same. .htaccess is the same

Comment: Unless whatever gump is is santiizing SQL, you're vulnerable to SQL injection here, if my username is, for example `'; DROP TABLE user; --`

Comment: Yes okay will need to escape all that. But how is it getting into the catch block here but not on test site is another question

Comment: Print the entire exception and stack trace and post it here, all we know is that SOMETHING threw an exception, we don't know for sure it's a CSRF exception thrown by whatever library or framework you're using

Comment: Does not seem to show much in the way of that code. I appreciate your help.

Comment: That's your error log, we want the stack trace, print $e->getTraceAsString()

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: Exception: Invalid CSRF token. in /home/nuaffili/public_html/lib/Nocsrf.php:55 Stack trace: #0 /home/nuaffili/public_html/login.php(7): NoCSRF::check('csrf_token', Array, true, 600, false) #1 {main} in /home/nuaffili/public_html/login.php on line 34

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getTraceAsString() on null in /home/nuaffili/public_html/login.php:34 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /home/nuaffili/public_html/login.php on line 34

Comment: Where did you print that, did you call getTraceAsString inside the exception block?

It does say invalid CSRF token, so sounds like you don't have a token and that's why?

Comment: yes inside the catch i put that statement. I generate the token after on page load and before the form submits